# Issues in changing Item Location results in a new Item Id square.com

Tags: square-connect

In `square.com > Items > Item Library (squareup.com/dashboard/items/library/)` you have the option to move an library item from one location to another, or even to two or more locations at once.  Fantastic, and just what we need.  (For reference, this option requires that you account makes use of more than one "location" `(Accounts & Settings > Locations (squareup.com/dashboard/locations) / UI` looks like this: )

[image: Location UI selector]

But there's a problem: the moment you change the item's location, behind the scenes the item's unique ID # `(item_id)` changes.

Item ID is the number that's referenced when you export an items list or make use of the Square API.  In other words the reference number that the Square suggests is permanently associated with an item is, in fact, very temporary and not very reliable the moment you make use of their locations feature.

The Locations feature is Square's suggested way to control whether or not an item appears in your Square Register App, and the Item ID is a central reference number for accounting and API use.

Looking for solutions and workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Catalog endpoints](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/catalog-overview), they have much more functionality for managing items across multiple locations.